# Fail to convert complicated type to bool?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, methods, types

I am building a method for a class, as shown below

```
const int PointArray::getSize() const
{
int c=0;
while(s[c])
{
    c++;
}
const con=c;
return con;
}
```

While the header file of the class is like this

```
class PointArray
{
    point *s;
    int len;

public:
    PointArray();
    virtual ~PointArray();

    const int getSize() const;
    
};


class point
{
private:
    int x,y;

public:
    point(int i=0,int j=0){x=i,y=j;};
};
```

then it raised error: could not convert '*(((point *)((const PointArray *)this)->PointArray::s) + ((sizetype)(((long long unsigned int)c) * 8)))' from 'point' to 'bool "

I have no idea of how to debug.

Comment: `getSize()` just needs to return `len`.

Comment: Which line in your [mre] triggers this error? (I see nothing close to it -- in particular, I see no `* 8` in your code.) Why do you expect that a `point` object can be converted to `bool`? (Often, this type of question is improved by adding the reason you think the compiler is wrong to raise the error.)

Comment: `s[c]` is of type `point`. What does it mean for a `point` to be true or false? Under what circumstances do you expect `while(s[c])` to run the body of the loop, or to exit the loop?

Answer (score 1):

C++ is trying to convert your class **Point** to primitive type **bool**. It fails because it doesnt know how to do it.

You can define implicit conversion operators in your class. This will allow c++ to do implicit conversion of your type (like you are doing in example).

This is how it would look:

```
class point
{
private:
    int x,y;

public:
    point(int i=0,int j=0){x=i,y=j;};
    operator bool() {
        /* your computation */
    };
};
```

Now when you use your class in place where c++ is exceptin bool , lamguage will convert your object to bool implicitly

Another way is to define method and call it.

```
    class point
    {
    private:
        int x,y;

    public:
        point(int i=0,int j=0){x=i,y=j;};
        bool asBool() {
        /* your computation */
        };
    };

// this is what will change in if statement
if(s[c].asBool()){
  // do something
}
```

In this case , i would prefer first solution (using conversion operator). Second solutions are for classes that are more complex (like persons).